# NodeJS - Events.js cannot read property forEach of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm facing an issue since 2 days and i can't figure out how to fix it. I've an error on forEach, so my application runs well and then stops without any explication.

Here is the code where the error happens.

```
    var easy = setInterval(function(){
        keywords.forEach(function(k) {
            tweetModel.find({keyword: k}).sort({date: -1}).limit(20).exec(function(err, data) {
                var score = [];
                var date = [];
                console.log(data);
                console.log(err)
                data.forEach(function (item) {
                    score.push(Math.floor(parseFloat(item.score) * 1000) / 1000);
                    date.push(item.date.getDate()+'/'+parseInt(item.date.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+item.date.getFullYear()+':'+parseInt(item.date.getHours() + 1)+':'+item.date.getMinutes());

                    tArrayStats[k] = score;
                    tArrayStats['date'] = date;
                });

            });

        });

        io.sockets.emit('stats',tArrayStats);
    },3000);
```

The error is thrown here

```
data.forEach(function (item)
```

but i can't figure out why ! Thanks for you help.

As asked there is the output of console log data :

[image]

**EDITED working code, thanks to @Ids van der Zee**

```
var easy = setInterval(function(){
    keywords.forEach(function(k) {

        tweetModel.find({keyword: k}).sort({date: -1}).limit(20).exec(function(err, data) {
            if (data && !err)
            {
                var score = [];
                var date = [];
                console.log(data);
                console.log(err)

                data.forEach(function (item) {
                    score.push(Math.floor(parseFloat(item.score) * 1000) / 1000);
                    date.push(item.date.getDate()+'/'+parseInt(item.date.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+item.date.getFullYear()+':'+parseInt(item.date.getHours() + 1)+':'+item.date.getMinutes());

                    tArrayStats[k] = score;
                    tArrayStats['date'] = date;
                });
            }

        });
    });

    io.sockets.emit('stats',tArrayStats);
},3000);
```

Comment: Two lines before that part you have `console.log(data)`, what's the output of that?

Comment: Updated my post with the output, then when the error drops i got "undedifned". I'm recveiving data from twit

Comment: The data you showed seems to be an object within an array --- > [{}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the line:

```
tweetModel.find({keyword: k}).sort({date: -1}).limit(20).exec(function(err, data) {
```

you are trying to find data corresponding to the keyword k, you are doing this for each keyword. If tweetModel does not contain the keyword you are looking for the data variable will be undefined. You can resolve this by checking if data is not undefined. Instead of

`data.forEach(function (item){...`

```
    if(data){
       data.forEach(function (item){...
```

Comment: Yeah i've figure out something like this, i've put the whole thing inside tweet.Model in a if (data && !err) so it should be good ! Thanks for your help !